# Replace new line with HTML tag in JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I have a JSON string for example:

```
"\nReferenceNo:20,Amount:100\nReferenceNo:30,Amount:200"
```

now i want to replace `\n` with `<br />` HTML tag. My code is given below

```
 var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(d.otherDetails);
 result=myJSONString.replace(RegExp("\n","g"), "<br />");
 alert(result);
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "\n" is a new line character. Different OSes display them differently (e.g., Windown requires `\r\n`). Where are you trying to display it? In the browser?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to fix references to line feeds. Most of them were wrong yet I don't think that fact affects the question (thus my edit).

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest you edit data before encoding or after decoding. Fiddling with serialised data structures is seldom a good idea.

Comment: Right, he didn't specify he wanted to display the line break in the browser. It could have been the console or somewhere else on the server.

Comment: @vol7ron i want to dispaly it in browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = myJSONString.replace(RegExp("\\n","g"), "\n");
```

It's because HTML is not interpreted in JSON and \n matches an actual new line, but `\n` matches an backslash followed by a n character.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```
\\n
```

Replacement string:

```
\n
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN6mX8/1)